# How can I add cue points in videos that are played with "MPMoviePlayerController"?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play videos. By adding cue points I mean, I want to fire some events when the current video being played reaches certain time (e.g. 1:03, 2:30).

How can I do that? How can I add listeners to the MPMoviePlayerController? Is it possible?

Comment: There are no such listeners. You will have to poll the currentPlaybackTime using a timer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `currentPlaybackTime` property of  [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  for getting the playback time, for adding the listener, something like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
  object:self.moviePlayer];
```

Comment: Halfway right, the OP would also need to use a timer that polls the currentPlaybackTime. That notification is only useful once the playback has finished - but hey, that might be a cuepoint as well :D.